# Update two devices on the same local network by one download

Tags: package-management, opensuse, download

I have two laptops with the same exact OS of openSUSE Leap 15.3 on my local network. I want to be able to update both of them with `sudo zypper ref` and `sudo zypper up` at the same time and by just **one** download of to-be-updated packages. How can I do that? I don't even know what's the terminology for such a thing. What I should I search about?

Comment: Typically the way it's done is to have a caching proxy server in your network that both of these laptops will use.

Comment: `apt-cacher-ng` will work for debian-style repositories.  Taking a look at that package may get you the terminology you need to find an equivalent for `zypper`

Answer (score 1):

In theory the simplest should be running `zypper up` with `-d` flag, which will just download packages without installing. Then copy `/var/cache/zypp/packages/` from one machine to the other.

Then `zypper up` should install those packages from the cache without downloading.

Comment: I cannot double-check your suggested solution now. But it looks reasonable.